# Try catch with containing for and if statement Java

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, try-catch

I am having an issue with my program.  The user is able to enter a grade into a GUI, but the grade has to be within grade 9 to 12.
This is what I've tried so far, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
int grade = Integer.parseInt(inputGrade.getText());
else
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 9; i < 13; i++)
            {
                if (grade == i)
                {
                grade = Integer.parseInt(inputGrade.getText());
                }
            } 
        }

        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {            
            for (int x = -1; x < 9; x++)
            {
                if (grade == x)
                {
                outputHint.setText("Grade not valid");
                }
            }
        }
```

There is no hint being outputted.

Any help please?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You seem to be missing the initial `if`

Comment: This code will not even compile.

Comment: Why thoses loops ? Just do `Integer.parseInt(inputGrade.getText());` and check the int later on if it's valid ! And in catch `outputHint.setText("Grade not valid");`

Comment: Why on earth would you use a for loop instead of writing `if(grade >= 9 && grade < 13)` etc. ?

Comment: @Kayaman If you're using `>=`, I'd use `<=` too :)

Comment: @Pendle - you're drastically over-complicating things here.

Comment: @notyou I used those to mimic the values in the code, as to avoid possible confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried something like this ?

```
try
{
    grade = Integer.parseInt(inputGrade.getText());
    if (grade >= 9 && grade <= 12) {
        // Valid
        outputHint.setText("Grade valid");
    } else {
        // Not valid
        outputHint.setText("Grade not valid");
    }
}
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
    outputHint.setText("Grade not valid");
}
```

Your also have the problem of comparing `grade` variable before you even put some value on it. And your `for` loops are not of use because you can just do a condition on your variable once it is an integer.

And at last, your exception will be `throw` only when `inputGrade.getText()` is a non-integer. So it is not taking into account your if condition so you can't even put there the condition for bad number afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do this.

```
    try{

        int grade = Integer.parseInt(inputGrade.getText());
        if(grade >= 9 && grade <= 12){
          // this is a good grade
           outputHint.setText("Grade valid");
        } else {
         // sorry, this is not a good grade.
         outputHint.setText("Grade not valid");
        }
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
         // sorry but you need to enter a number !!
        }
```

Comment: You print `Grade not valid` whether it's valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try  {
        int grade = Integer.parseInt(inputGrade.getText());
        if (grade < 9 || grade > 12) {
            outputHint.setText("Grade not valid");
        }
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        outputHint.setText("Grade not valid");
    }
```

Comment: You should probably comment or otherwise explain where the valid situation is in this.

Answer (score 0):

Catching `NumberFormatException` will give an exception only if the entered input cannot be converted to `Integer`. And probably you are missing the initial `if` too.